# check number is multiple of another

Tags: java

I am using Use the remainder operator for number is multiple of another . If first number is 3 and second number is 15 then

```
if (3 % 15 == 0) {

}
```

then it works (Does not go into if). But now if first number is 3 and second number is 4000 then it not works condition is still true

```
if (3 % 4000 == 0) {

}
```

here it should not go into if case. but here condition is true. Why is it so?

Comment: No, it really *isn't* true. You've misdiagnosed it. Try to come up with a short but complete program to demonstrate the problem - you'll find that `3 % 4000` really is `3`.

Comment: Given your current code snippet. None of the `if` condition will be true. I don't understand how you get that result you are saying.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you carefully test your program, you'll see that in neither case the body of the `if` statement is executed.

The reason is that you've got the arguments to `%` the wrong way round.

The `if` should read:

```
if (4000 % 3 == 0) {
```

The `%` operator returns the remainder of dividing the *first* argument by the *second*.

Comment: Please add comment when downvote. because this ans is correct from my side +1.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question - he's asking why it's true (which it isn't...), and this has nothing to do with that.

Comment: I see no indication that the OP really wants to find a remainder modulo 3... and it has nothing to do with going into the `if` (which won't happen either way round).

Comment: As per my view this answer is correct so +1 for this

Comment: Okay, downvote removed because of edit. Also, the OP appears to have changed the question or something @NPE... It still doesn't really make sense :/

Answer (score 0):

% [modulo division](http://www.ibiblio.org/java/course/week2/15.html) will return the remainder of a/b (a divided by b)

So here `3%15`  and 3%4000 are equal to 3

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have small number divided or remainder by larger number. which you have

```
if(3 % 4000==0){}
```

So before doing this kind of operation you can use a method and passed 2 numbers to it, which will first check if 1st number is greater or lesser than number than it will perform accordingly.
i.e.

```
    //you may change the return type.
    void multiple(int a, int b)
    {
      if(a>b)
      {
         if(a % b == 0)
         {
           //TO DO Code here
         }   
      }
      else
      {
         if(b%a==0)
        {
          //TO DO Code here    
        }
     }
    }
```

Comment: -1: the code requires you to duplicate the stuff you want to execute, is terribly formatted, and doesn't even run.

Comment: @Doorknob I have edited the code. and if you feel that it is getting duplicated please let me know how to remove duplication of code.

Comment: `if (a % b == 0 || b % a == 0) { ... }`, but anyway this doesn't even answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine with every value, the remainder will always be 3, so 'if' will not execute. If u want to check with 0, the better way to write 'if' will be,

```
if (!(3 % 4000)){
    // Code to execute
}
```

In this case it only executes when there is a remainder 0. And also check with the variable type once.

One possibility is if u declare it as signed short int (0 to 127) and store 4000 to it, overflow occurs and the variable value will be set to minimum (that is, zero(0)). So, in your case it executes the 'if'. Just to give u an idea.

Answer (score 0):

When a%b == 0 then a is multiple of b if a>= b

for a < b , a  will never be a multiple b unless it is zero